# Android JNI Throwing Fault with no exceptions - Trying to call a callback

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, jnienv

JNI causing a fault with no exception

Seems to happen in a few different areas but usually within this code:

```
void /*__stdcall*/ OutgoingCallbackHandler(int device_id, unsigned char* buffer, int size)
    {
        LockTools();

        JNIEnv* env = ::GetJNIEnvForCurrentThread();

        if (env == NULL)
        {
            LOGF("Environment couldn't be found for callback thread!");
            return;
        }

        for (int scan = 0; scan < callbacks.size(); ++scan)
        {
            if (callbacks[scan].type == CallbackInfo::OUTGOING)
            {
                jbyteArray jba = NULL;
                if (size <= 0)
                {
                    // we don't want to create a byte array if
                    // we have no data to represent.
                }
                else
                {


                    jba = env->NewByteArray(size); //THIS IS WHERE CRASH HAPPENS


                    env->SetByteArrayRegion(jba, 0, size, (const jbyte*)buffer);
                }

                env->CallVoidMethod(callbacks[scan].object, callbacks[scan].callback, device_id, jba);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(jba);
            }
        }

        UnlockTools();
    }
```

We have checked the env still points to a valid memory location, the size passed in is within spec

This starts to happen after its been called a few times

Is there better ways to debug JNI issues?

We have also checked for JNI specific exceptions directly above the line that seems to throw a fault

Comment: This should produce a native stack trace.  Did you register this thread with the VM?  Did you hold a reference to something that may no longer exist (or at least no longer be functional) on the Java side, such as after a lifecycle event?

Comment: Do you attach and detach all threads carefully? If you use **env** on a different thread, it will still be a valid pointer, but JNI calls will fail.